# Linked List traversal by pointer in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

In programming, we have to do `var = var + sum;` and we can write it as `var += sum;`.

So, in a linked list, can we write `temp = temp->next;` as `temp->=next;`?

Comment: No that does not make sense there is no `->=` operator. You need to use `temp = temp->next;`

Comment: `var += sum;` works because there is a `+=` operator

Comment: This would have been trivial to test out yourself. If you find yourself asking, "Can I do this?", try it first and find out.

Comment: Maybe they can add it for C++25?  Now that we've got the spaceship operator, we might as well throw in the kitchen sink :)

Answer (score 0):

> So in the linked list can we write `temp = temp->next;`
> as - `temp->=next;`

No, such an operator does not exist in C++.